# How to store remote images and audio files in Android?

Tags: android

I developed one app it is displaying image and play audio along with the image. For this application I want to get images and audio files from remote server and store those on inside apk

1. I heard about SQLite in mobile.is this database hold image,mp3 files
2. I don't want to store images sd card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can store images and audio files in sqlite as a `BLOB` format. You can check these links to find how it is being done

https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html

https://web.archive.org/web/20181024035526/http://www.anddev.org/png_image_--und-gt_sqlite_db_--und-gt_imageview-t7188.html

Though some people store images on sqlite not many store audio files there. It is always better to read it from a local file(somewhere in ur SDCard or Internal m/y) than from a database.